# python csv writter adds extra quotes

Tags: python, csv, quotes

I am using csv writter to create txt file.
When merging lists extra quotes are added. (separator it \t)

the final list I have before inserting is

```
['20160501-20160531', '719', '1-4', '(1\t1\t12:00-19:00\t1)', '(1\t1\t12:00-19:00\t1)&(2\t1\t01:00-06:00\t2)']
```

when writting to the file  i get this

```
20160501-20160531   719 1-4 "(1 1   12:00-19:00 1)" "(1 1   12:00-19:00 1)&(2   1   01:00-06:00 2)"
```

why are there extra quotes?

All is good (tab delimited and all ) except extra quotes are causing problems

I tried with  quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE but I only get an error for escapechar not set

this is my code

```
 for rec in formJson['presentDays']:
        period = '%s-%s'% (scheduleS, scheduleE)
        if not rec['workers']:
            continue
        else:
            workers = ' '.join(str(e) for e in rec['workers'])
            for rr in rec['data']:
                range = '%s-%s' %(rr['loadFrom'],rr['loadTo'])
                #prva vrstica v subdata je condition
                request = rr['subdata'][0]
                request_days = ' '.join(str(x) for x in request['days'])
                request_works = str(request['works'])
                request_time = '%s-%s' %(request['timeFrom'],request['timeTo'])
                request_how = str(request['how'])
                request_row = "(" + request_days + '\t'+ request_works + '\t'+ request_time + '\t'+ request_how + ")"

                #gremo vse nasledne zapise, ki so condition
                itersubdata = iter(rr['subdata'])
                next(itersubdata)
                conditions_rows = []
                for r in itersubdata:
                    condition_days = str(r['days'][0])
                    condition_works = str(r['works'])
                    condition_time = '%s-%s' %(r['timeFrom'],r['timeTo'])
                    condition_how = str(r['how'])
                    condition_row = '(%s\t%s\t%s\t%s)' % (condition_days, condition_works, condition_time, condition_how)
                    conditions_rows.append(condition_row)
                conditions = '&'.join(x for x in conditions_rows)
                record = [period, workers,range,str(request_row), conditions]
                print "record ", record
                output.writerow(record)
```

Any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: All fields that contain your delimiter `\t` will have to be quoted! Otherwise they will be split across multiple columns when being read.

Comment: File is being read by another program (custom read) so it is no need to fit in excel or smth simillar

Comment: The only solution I came out is not to use csv writer but normal write to file     `file.write(period + '\t'+ workers+ '\t'+ range+ '\t'+request_row + '\t'+ conditions+' \r\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need quotes for strings containing white-spaces (tabs in this case).